# extract info out of XML tag - RUBY

Tags: ruby, xml

I have an xml tag like this

```
    <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000511" name="ms level" value="1"/>
```

How can i get the value of ms level (1)?
Please, don't suggest nokogiri or rexml. I want to learn how I can parse info out while I read the file, line by line.
Thank you.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you want to parse HTML with an HTML parser? There are ways to process the file a bit at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = '<cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000511" name="ms level" value="1"/>'

md = str.match(/
     name="(.*?)"        #Match name=" followed by any character(.), 0 or more times(*), captured in group 1 (), followed by...
     \s*                 #whitespace(\s), 0 or more times(*), followed by...
     value="(\d+)"       #value=", followed by a number(\d), one or more times(+), captured in group 2 ().
/x) #x-flag: ignore whitespace in pattern, which allows you to write the regex on mutliple lines and add comments like these.

if md
  name, value = md.captures   #captures => an Array containing the matches for each of the parenthesized groups in the regex.
  puts "#{name}(#{value})"
end

--output:--
ms level(1)
```

Comment: *Please, don't suggest nokogiri or rexml.*--How about in the comments?  There are many ways the regex above will break depending on the actual string.  And when you tire of patching the regex over and over again to handle new strings that won't parse correctly, and your regex is a snarled, tangled, unreadable, and unmaintainable mess, then you will understand why people advise using nokogiri. rexml on the other hand is a relic from the wasteland known as the Ruby Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the other readers who haven't prematurely ruled out Nokogiri. You can process a file line by line and process each line as a `DocumentFragment`.

```
require 'nokogiri'

line = '<cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000511" name="ms level" value="1"/>'

fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(line)
cvparam = fragment.first_element_child

puts cvparam.attributes.values_at('name', 'value')

#=> ["ms level", "1"]
```